# When should I use getApplicationContext().getBean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When should I use `getApplicationContext().getBean(<someclass>,args)`?

Is the above statement similar to  `SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();`
If so what is the use case of getBean ?

I am unable to understand why it is necessary to call getBean from application context.I am a newbie to Sprin-boot application.
Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Please go through spring docs and get hold of dependency injection and post a valid question. This is the obvious and most fundamental concept of spring framework.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should avoid such calls as much as it possible since it will couple your business code to `spring-core`. You should register your components (beans) in the application context (with java-config, xml, component-scan, etc) and just ask required dependencies using `@Autowired` or `@Inject`.

> Is the above statement similar to  SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();

Well, not really. You can lookup bean by class yes, but you can do it by interface as well.

Besides you're not taken into account a *scope* of a bean. Some beans might be *singletons*, some of them might be *prototype* and some of them might even have a custom scope bounded to the current phase of the moon.

A nice explanation of the principal idea could be [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) here.